# Ubuntu 18.10 is much slower with Wayland than X.org

Tags: performance, wayland

I have just recently installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my desktop. There is an issue which I can't understand: if I start a session with Wayland (choosing this while logging in), the system noticeably slower. I mean, even the mouse and typing are with a small (but noticeable) delay. If I run `htop`, I see that all the cores are constantly 40-50% busy, and the most CPU-hungry processes are `gnome-shell`.

#### System info

Output of `inxi -SCG` (v. 3.0.24-00) under Wayland:

```
System:
  Host: mydesktop Kernel: 4.18.0-13-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.30.1 Distro: Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) 
CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i5-9600K bits: 64 type: MCP 
  L2 cache: 9216 KiB 
  Speed: 1482 MHz min/max: 800/4600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2315 2: 2317 
  3: 2318 4: 2318 5: 2320 6: 2320 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.20.1 driver: i915 
  resolution: 3840x2160~30Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 18.2.2
```

The same under X11:

```
System:
  Host: mydesktop Kernel: 4.18.0-13-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.30.1 Distro: Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) 
CPU:
  Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i5-9600K bits: 64 type: MCP 
  L2 cache: 9216 KiB 
  Speed: 801 MHz min/max: 800/4600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
  3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.1 driver: i915 resolution: 3840x2160~30Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 18.2.2
```

I have a built-in Intel graphic card, the motherboard is ASRock Z390 Extreme4.

#### UPD

Under X11, there is another issue though. If I try to open the system settings, I am forcefully logged out. I created a [separate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114098) about this.

**Disclaimer**: I am not that advanced Ubuntu/Linux user.

Where can I look into the problem in my Ubuntu? What to start with?

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `inxi -SCG -! 31 -y 80`. Also if you made edits to `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`. Yoy could help developers by debuging wayland 
with [this tool](https://github.com/wmww/wayland-debug) ([here in discurse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/a-better-way-to-debug-wayland/9176)).

Comment: I get `Error 22: Unsupported option: -!
Check -h for correct parameters.
` - what should be the correct option?

Comment: Maybe you have an older version of `inxi` (mine is 2.3.56-00 (2018-01-17)). Don't worry, just the output of `inxi -SCG` should be OK. Did you update your drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`? You can compare both with [some benchmark tool](https://www.howtogeek.com/111617/how-to-benchmark-your-linux-system-3-open-source-benchmarking-tools/) like `gtkperf` or [pts (phoronix-test-suite package)](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) and edit your question with the results.

Comment: `inxi` output added. Running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` gives 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: Running `gtkperf` under Wayland logged me out from Ubuntu (perhaps, some other issues are present). Running the same under X.org finished fine in 1.21 s.

Comment: Apparently, there is another issue with X11. I updated the post.

Comment: I would add `inxi -G` from an X11 session to compare. Your results of inxi from wayland have 2 significant issues, "OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe" will result in poor performance, the resolution @ ~30Hz seems wrong also. Or you could try an install of 19.04-dev, maybe your hardware is better supported in wayland

Comment: @doug I added full output of X11 session. What can I change llvmpipe to in order to improve performance? It's my working computer, so I can't really play with dev versions of OS. :(

Comment: @doug and what is wrong with 30Hz? The current configuration doesn't support 60Hz in 3840x2160 resolution - and I prefer more stuff on the screen, as I don't notice any difference 30Hz vs 60 Hz.

Comment: Well if 30Hz is the limit, fine . You're getting the same as far as llvmpipe being used in X11 also. If you're fine with that in X11 instead of preferred Mesa DRI then just use X11 & try to solve your issue with X11. I guess you could try a newer kernel at some point from the kernel-ppa/mainline..

Comment: I've just installed Mesa DRI according to this: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/install-mesa-18-0-4-ubuntu-18-04-lts/ - and now, when I am trying to log in to Wayland session, I am being logged out immediately.

Comment: ...on the other hand, newer Mesa solved my other problem (with opening Settings under X11).